# When does $\det \begin{pmatrix} A & X \\ X^T & A \end{pmatrix} = (\det A)^2 + (\det X)^2$?

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, matrices, determinants, block-matrices

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ real symmetric matrix.
Let
$$
M = \begin{pmatrix} A & X  \\ X^T & A   \end{pmatrix}
$$
where $X$ is a real invertible $n \times n$ matrix. I am interested in finding $X$ such that
$$
\det M = (\det A)^2 + (\det X)^2. 
$$

Given $A$, is there a systematic way of finding such $X$ under some hypotheses?

Any suggestions, comments or reference for a related topic is very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: This case should be amenable to a brute-force search.

Comment: for $A=0$ no nonzero $X$ exists that satisfies the equation, while $X=0$ satisfies it for any $A$; are you sure you don't want a minus sign instead of a plus sign in your equation?

Comment: Just a small remark: It suffices to consider the case that $A$ is diagonal, since $A$ may be daigonalized via an orthogonal matrix $U$, and then we can replace $M$ by $VMV^{T}$, where $V$ is the "direct sum" of two copies of $U$.

Answer (score 3):

$$B=\left[\matrix{1&1&1&1\\1&1&-1&-1\\-1&-1&-1&1\\-1&1&-1&1}\right]$$
and probably many other solutions.  I'm also voting to close because you didn't pose a research-level problem.  If you have an interesting general case, pose that.

Comment: Thank you for the example, let me change the problem.